# gpg: Warning: not using '...' as default key: No secret key

Tags: gnupg

I recently exported my secret key to a Windows server, and now it won't let me encrypt anything.

When I run `gpg --list-secret-keys`, it shows up:

```
sec   rsa2048 2019-06-21 [SC] [expires: 2023-06-25]
      C86XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6A3
uid           [ultimate] xxx@xxx.com
ssb   rsa2048 2019-06-21 [E] [expires: 2023-06-25]
```

And it's also in the public key ring `gpg --list-keys`:

```
pub   rsa2048 2019-06-21 [SC] [expires: 2023-06-25]
      C86XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6A3
uid           [ultimate] xxx@xxx.com
sub   rsa2048 2019-06-21 [E] [expires: 2023-06-25]
```

But when I try to encrypt a file I get this error:

```
gpg: Warning: not using 'C86XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6A3' as default key: No secret key
gpg: all values passed to '--default-key' ignored
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: 20211215.0101.pgp: sign+encrypt failed: No secret key
```

Here's the command I'm trying to execute:

```
gpg --yes --recipient 998XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX918 --output $fileName --sign -encrypt $fileName.pgp
```

Comment: Is this command run as part of a script?  If so, does the script set any environment variables?

Comment: It is part of a script that builds the file first, but no, it doesn't set any environment variables.

Comment: Is the script run as `sudo`? The error your getting means no secret keys are present for gnupg in the HOME environment.

Comment: Oh that's what it was. It was using the wrong home environment. Thank you!